# Extract a number from a string getting number format exception

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing, automation

Im having trouble taking a number value from a string on a webpage im testing.
Im currently using:

```
String total_points = potential_points.getText();
System.out.println("Potential points are: " + total_points);
int pot_points = Integer.parseInt(total_points);
```

The problem is the selector is actually returning two strings aswell:
"Potential Points"
":"
"1476"

How can i extract the 1476 and use it as an int. Ive attached the html.

[image: HTML]

Potential Points: 1473

Entry:Free To Play

Comment: share the HTML in text format instead of screenshot.

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: I see the the image , add in text format.

Comment: What is the 'potential_points' variable's type?

Comment: Its a Webelement, So im changing the Weblement to a string and then into an int. But it wont change to an int because of the "Potential Pints" and ":". Im trying to remove them so i can use the value in a calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the result by using substring method as below

```
    String total_points = potential_points.getText();
    int startIndex=total_points.indexOf(":")+2;
    int endIndex=total_points.length();
    String result=total_points.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
    int no=Integer.parseInt(result);
```

Simplified the above code as below

```
    String result=total_points.substring(total_points.indexOf(":")+2,total_points.length());
    int no=Integer.parseInt(result);
```

Comment: Sorry Ive actually just changed the code above, so when i use potential_points.getText();  it returns "Potential Points" ":" "1476". the string total points is Potential Points:1476 (or whatever the value is, as it changes each run) then it wont change for me into an int because of the two strings.

Comment: I have changed the temp as "total_points ".So, you can use the above logic to extract the required no alone. If you want to convert it as int, then do the parsing , else keep the substring alone

Comment: @Subburaj : Something like this would be more beneficial : string s = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", e);

Comment: Even the value changes for each run, the format will be like "Potential Points" ":" "<<no>>" right?

Comment: @cruisepandey:  Whether it will workout? Since, both the values are available within the same tag?

Comment: The two strings will always be there just the value will change

Comment: @user9686029: then you can use the above logic to extract the value

Comment: Ive tried the code above and its returning "7" but the error is gone

Comment: @Subburaj : Those two are textNodes , javascript executor provides more beneficial and readable format. I wanted to give the answer but OP refuses to share code in text format,so it is not worthy IMO.

Comment: then you need to add to replace +4 as +2 in startIndex and remove the -1 from the endIndex.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but what does the +2 actually do in this scenario?

Comment: Here we need to identify the startIndex of the first digit from the : position. So, it should be +2. But, When I copied your test data  I got some empty space and that time first digit position was changed for me .

Comment: @cruisepandey:Thanks for giving your suggestion!!! I will use it in future, whenever required.

Comment: @Subburaj : We should use it in cases where we need to differentiate between text Nodes.

Comment: @cruisepandey:I got it.I have assumed that is a single text node.